# Is there a pythonic way to count the number of leading matching characters in two strings?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string-matching, string-length

For two given strings, is there a pythonic way to count how many consecutive characters of both strings (starting at postion 0 of the strings) are identical?

For example in `aaa_Hello` and `aa_World` the "leading matching characters" are `aa`, having a length of 2. In `another` and `example` there are no leading matching characters, which would give a length of 0.

---

I have written a function to achive this, which uses a for loop and thus seems very unpythonic to me:

```
def matchlen(string0, string1): # Note: does not work if a string is ''

    for counter in range(min(len(string0), len(string1))):
        # run until there is a mismatch between the characters in the strings
        if string0[counter] != string1[counter]:         
            # in this case the function terminates
            return(counter)

    return(counter+1)

matchlen(string0='aaa_Hello', string1='aa_World') # returns 2
matchlen(string0='another', string1='example') # returns 0
```

Comment: I'm not from Python but is a `for` loop unpythonic? Your function looks good (at least to a nonpythonic). Regex won't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unexpected function in os.path, [commonprefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix), can help (because it is not limited to file paths, any strings work).  It can also take in more than 2 input strings.

> Return the longest path prefix (taken character-by-character) that is a prefix of all paths in list. If list is empty, return the empty string ('').

```
from os.path import commonprefix
print(len(commonprefix(["aaa_Hello","aa_World"])))
```

#### output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `zip` and `enumerate`:

```
def matchlen(str1, str2):
    i = -1 # needed if you don't enter the loop (an empty string)
    for i, (char1, char2) in enumerate(zip(str1, str2)):
        if char1 != char2:
            return i
    return i+1
```

Comment: Hi @S. Pellegrino, welcome on the site! Thank you for your answer. I'm I getting it right, that all solutions (Amadans, yours and mine) bassically do the same: looping through the characters and counting the matches?

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import takewhile
common_prefix_length = sum(
    1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x[0]==x[1], zip(string0, string1)))
```

`zip` will pair up letters from the two strings; `takewhile` will yield them as long as they're equal; and `sum` will see how many there are.

As bobble bubble says, this indeed does exactly the same thing as your loopy thing. Its sole pro (and also its sole con) is that it is a one-liner. Take it as you will.